# How to pass a hidden variable value to href onclick function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, model-view-controller

I have a hidden variable which stores an ID. In another view i have href tag from which I am calling a function with with I need to send this ID as a paramater.

my hidden variable:

```
<input type="hidden" id="CID" value="@Model.CID">

< a href="#!" onclick="openDlg('@item.Name', 'here i want that hidden variable value'") >/<a>
```

Please help

Comment: Replace `'here i want that hidden variable value'` with `@Model.CID` (do you really need the hidden input?)

Comment: I have the hidden variable in a different view.. And I dont have value of CID in the model in this view's page

Comment: How on earth do you expect to get the value from a different view. You need to pass the value to the view you have the `<a>` tag in

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm new to mvc. I'm not sure. One of my friends suggested to get the value using Jscript like: `var ID=$('#CID').value(); `and it worked

Comment: Yes, that would work if the input is on the same page as the script - its identical to using `@Model.CID` as I indicated above. But it cant possibly work if its in a different view.